# Wordpress + sidebar + Avada + headache

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have a Wordpress problem that I can't fix....

Woocommerce is using a sidebar with product filters.

I'd simply like to hide the sidebar + filters on Woocommerce parent pages.

I first tried by adding a class which I could hide the sidebar content with css, like this :

```
add_filter( 'fusion_sidebar_1_class', 'usl_wc_product_cats_css_body_class' );

function usl_wc_product_cats_css_body_class( $classes )
    {
        if( is_tax( 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $cat = get_queried_object();
        if( 0 == $cat->parent  ) $classes[] = 'usl-parent';
}
return $classes;
}
```

But this obviously leaves the main content at 80% or so.

So I'm now trying to remove the sidebar instead using a mix of the above and some example code from the Avada help pages. Code is below but totally doesn't work! Can anyone please help?

```
function remove_woo_commerce_sidebar() {
    global $avada_woocommerce;
    {
    if( is_tax( 'product_cat' ) ) 
        {
          $cat = get_queried_object();
          if( 0 == $cat->parent  )  
          remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', array( $avada_woocommerce, 'add_sidebar' ), 10 );
        }        
    }

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'remove_woo_commerce_sidebar' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this through CSS? Just change the selector to match the page type you want to affect

```
.woocommerce-page #content .single_wrap {
float: none;
width: 100%;
}

.woocommerce-page #sidebar {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: That's kinda what the first bit of code does, but without yet being amended to also target the main content. The theme I'm using (Avada) does all sorts of dynamic sizing of content so wanted to try and remove the sidebar completely before hacking away at the CSS further

Comment: My understanding of Avada (I haven't used it for a while) is that you can remove it through the UI. https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/sidebars/sidebars-in-avada/ and https://theme-fusion.com/documentation/avada/sidebars/sidebars-in-avada/#iLightbox[0d56eb69245a651ec21]/0

Comment: That's right, but the settings are either 'show sidebar in woo' or 'don't show sidebar in woo' I need to show it on the subcategories but not on the parent category pages. I think I probably need to target something called 'body.has-sidebar' with an action but can't quite work out how....

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't find a neat way to unload the sidebar so added an extra body class so I could target both the main content & sidebar with this :

```
add_filter( 'body_class','usl_body_classes' );

function usl_body_classes( $classes ) 
    {
        if( is_tax( 'product_cat' ) ) {
        $cat = get_queried_object();
        if( 0 == $cat->parent  ) $classes[] = 'usl_full_woo_css';
    }
    return $classes;    
}
```